# How to downgrade Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

My server hangs when it tries to install Nokogiri via Capistrano.

When I manually run `bundle install` on the server, it hangs on the `mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)` part, which is a dependency for Nokogiri.

When I open my Gemfile.lock it has this line of code:

```
nokogiri (1.6.7.1)
  mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
```

This is the new version of Nokogiri. I only have 1.6.5 in my local computer. When I use:

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~>1.6.5'
```

and run update it still has the 1.6.7.1 version. When I just change it to 1.6.5 manually, it still hangs.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~>1.6.5'
```

means any version that matches `1.6.x`, therefore `1.6.7.1` matches that pattern. If you want to use 1.6.5 you need to specify

```
gem 'nokogiri', '=1.6.5'
```

or you can use a range

```
gem 'nokogiri', '>=1.6.5', '< 1.6.6'
```

Comment: Now I was able to downgrade it. However, it still hangs on `Using mini-portile 0.6.2` when I hit CTRL+C It says that it could not install nokogiri

Comment: That's a different problem. Please open a different question with enough information to debug it.